# How can I pivot multiple columns and maintain their relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I've been beating my head against the wall for 3 days on this, so hoping someone may be able to help me.

I have a set of data that I need to do some pivoting to, but can't quite get the syntax figured out.

Sample Data Set:

```
Employee    LastName    FirstName   Status  Location    GroupBU     DeductionDesc   Active      Field                   Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       SMITH       JOHN            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS CHILD      Y       Deduction               8502
12345       SMITH       JOHN            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS CHILD      Y       EmployeeAmtPct          0.1
12345       SMITH       JOHN            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS CHILD      Y       EmployeeAnnSalary       10000
12345       SMITH       JOHN            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS CHILD      Y       EmployeeInsAmt          10000
67890       SMITH       JANE            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS SPOUSE     Y       Deduction               8501
67890       SMITH       JANE            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS SPOUSE     Y       EmployeeAmtPct          0.357
67890       SMITH       JANE            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS SPOUSE     Y       EmployeeAnnSalary       50000
67890       SMITH       JANE            A       5555        9999    LIFE INS SPOUSE     Y       EmployeeInsAmt          50000
```

Desired outcome:

```
Employee    LastName    FirstName   Status  Location    GroupBU [LIFE INS CHILD]    Deduction   EmployeeAmtPct  EmployeeAnnSalary   EmployeeInsAmt  [LIFE INS SPOUSE]   Deduction   EmployeeAmtPct  EmployeeAnnSalary   EmployeeInsAmt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       SMITH       JOHN        A       5555        9999    LIFE INS CHILD      8502        0.1             10000               10000           NULL                NULL        NULL            NULL                NULL
67890       SMITH       JANE        A       5555        9999    NULL                NULL        NULL            NULL                NULL            LIFE INS SPOUSE     8501        0.357           50000               50000
```

Obviously, in my "Desired Outcome", I have duplicate column names, which won't work, so I assume that I would need to come up with a way to append/prepend something to each of them in order to make them unique, but haven't been able to figure out how to do that. This would also be necessary to associate the different Fields & Values to the appropriate "DeductionDesc" in final output. It's also been requested that the value in "DeductionDesc" be the column name in the final output, and if a value does not exist, it just be NULL (demonstrated in output).

My Source data was created using an UNPIVOT, as it seems like that would make it more likely to be successful.

I have about 65 unique values in "DeductionDesc", and approximately 3500 unique employee records.

Here's the current (and about 4th iteration) of the code I have:

```
select * 
from
    (
    select Employee,LastName,FirstName,Status,Location,GroupBU,DeductionDesc,Active,Field,Value 
    FROM MyTable
    ) unpvt
PIVOT 
    (
    MAX([DeductionDesc])
    FOR [DeductionDesc] IN ([LIFE INS SPOUSE],[LIFE INS CHILD UNUM POST TAX])
    ) pvt
PIVOT 
    (
    MAX([Value])
    FOR [Field] IN ([InsPlan],[EmployeeAnnSalary],[InsCoverage],[InsEmployeeRate],[EmployeeAmtPct],[InsLevelDesc],[InsCoverageDesc],[InsCarrierDesc],[InsPlanDesc],[InsLevel],[Deduction],[EmployeeInsAmt],[InsCarrier])
    ) pvt
```

For readability and simplicities sake, I have removed most of the items from the first PIVOT in the "IN" statement, but initially had all 65 listed there.

Any help anyone might be able to provide to get me to my desired outcome would be greatly appreciated. If additional information is needed, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: I dont see a PIVOT in your desire output. Can you explain the logic?

Comment: @Pat This is in SQL 2008 R2

Comment: @Juan Carlos I am trying to pivot the "DescriptionDesc" column, and keep the associated other columns next to it. e.g. The Deduction, and various "Rate" or "Amt" columns still next to the the same DescriptionDesc that they are tied to. Hope that makes sense (This is also my first foray into PIVOT, and have scoured many other posts looking for something similar)

Comment: Use case statement it's work

Comment: Sorry I dont see it. Why are two Deduction Fields? Can you reduce the number of fields? Try to make your example simpler. Ex with Employee and LastName column is enough. The other 4 following columns doesnt change the problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Unfortunately I cannot remove those. The Deduction value is a unique code associated with each DeductionDesc. I need to (likely) rename the Deduction,EmployeeAmtPct,EmployeeAnnSalary,EmployeeInsAmt columns so that they are unique and associatable to the DeductionDesc they are tied to.

Comment: I mean you can remove to explain the problem, If you have 2 column or you have 4 at the begining doesnt change the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server syntax here, but the concept is applicable to most SQL flavors. One way to attack this is to use a CASE construct:

```
SELECT tA.Employee, tA.LastName, tA.FirstName, tA.Status, tA.Location,    
       tA.GroupBU, tB.Deduction, tB.EmployeeAmtPct

FROM your_table AS tA 

INNER JOIN

(SELECT Employee, SUM(CASE WHEN Field = 'Deduction'      THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Deduction,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN Field = 'EmployeeAmtPct' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS EmployeeAmtPct
                  ...and so on for all the fields that you want to transpose...
 FROM your_table 
 GROUP BY Employee) AS tB ON tA.Employee = tB.Employee
```

I'm just putting Deduction and EmployeeAmtPct in for sake of brevity here. Basically, this is a cross-tabulation query. It just does selective summing based on what category 'Field' falls into. The ELSE clause in the CASE statement ensures that there is always a value to sum.

Comment: Thank you. I am testing this now, and suspected a CASE/JOIN would be required. Running into some conversion issues, so I'll troubleshoot that and update once complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind going dynamic  (change #myTable to your table name)

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''

Select @SQL = @SQL +SqlExpr
 From (
        Select Top 100 Percent *
              ,SqlExpr = case when ColNr=1 then char(13)+','+QuoteName(DeductionDesc)+'=max(case when DeductionDesc='''+DeductionDesc+''' and Field='''+Field+''' then DeductionDesc else null end)' else '' end +char(13)+','+QuoteName(Field)+'=max(case when DeductionDesc='''+DeductionDesc+''' and Field='''+Field+''' then Value else null end)'
         From (
                Select Distinct 
                       DeductionDesc
                      ,Field
                      ,ColNr  = Row_Number() over (Partition By DeductionDesc Order By Field)
                 From  #MyTable
              ) A Order By 1,3
      ) A 

Select @SQL = '
Select Employee
      ,LastName
      ,FirstName
      ,Status
      ,Location
      ,GroupBU'+@SQL+'
 From  #MyTable
 Group By 
       Employee
      ,LastName
      ,FirstName
      ,Status
      ,Location
      ,GroupBU 
'
--Print(@SQL)
Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

[image]